# Spring boot @Transactioanl method running on multiple threads

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-transactions

In my spring boot application, I have parallel running multiple threads of following `@Transactioanl` method.

```java
@Transactional
public void run(Customer customer) {

    Customer customer = this.clientCustomerService.findByCustomerName(customer.getname());
    if(customer == null) {
        this.clientCustomerService.save(customer);
    }

    // another database oparations
}
```

When this running on multiple threads at the same time, since customer object will not be save until end of the transaction block, is there any possibility to duplicate customers in the database?

Comment: If by "duplicate customers" you mean "two or more customers with the same e.g. name", yes. But in a more broad view it depends how you define "same". If you have e.g. a auto increment ID identifying your customers you will never get two customers with the same ID.

Comment: @Smutje Yes, "duplicate customers" means "two or more customers with the same name". So is there any way to implement this without duplicating customers?

Comment: Sure, you could `synchronize` access to your `clientCustomerService` to exclude multiple threads from creating the same customer over and over again. AFAIK the pattern was similar to `synchronized (object) { if (condition) { synchronized (object) { doSomething(); } } } }`

Answer (score 1):

If your customer has an `@Id`field which define a Primary Key column in Customer database, the database will throw you an exception like `javax.persistence.EntityExistsException`. Even if you run your code on multiple threads, at a point in time, maybe at the database level, only one will acquire a lock on the new inserted row. Also you must define `@Version` column/field at top entity level in order to use optimistic-locking. More details about this you can find [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-dataIntegrityviolationexception).

Comment: There is a @Id field, but I need to get rid of two or more customers with the same `name`. And I want to use existing customer obj (if already that customer is in the db), while commiting the transaction rather than just throwing an exception or duplicating customer objects. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: You want to check if a customer with the same name already exists in the database?

Comment: Yes, exactly; I did that in the above code sample, but the problem is there is a time gap between that checking and transaction committing. At that time, the same customer can be inserted to the database from another thread. Then there will be duplicate customers in the database

Comment: And what's the problem? you can't avoid this. If you will try to insert two objects with the same key this will be the result ...